# How to log copied items during the backup script?

Tags: powershell

I need to make basic / or more advanced backup script that would copy items from folder A to folder B and then log what it did.

This copies the files just fine:

```
$source = 'path\gamybinis\*'
$dest = 'path\backup'

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-5)
}| Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -Force

Write-Host "Backup started"
Pause
```

But after this I can't write the log with | Out-File, So I've tried this:

```
$source = 'path\gamybinis\*'
$dest = 'path\backup'
$logFile = 'path\log.txt'

$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-5)
}

foreach($item in $items){
    Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
    Copy-Item -Path "$source\$item" -Destination $dest -Recurse -Force
}

Write-Host "Backup started"
Pause
```

This one does absolutely nothing, what exactly am I doing wrong?

(Advanced script part would be: backing up recently modified files then files should be archived to .rar/.zip, log file have to have structure that is easily readable and log file should have information which user was working on the device during the backup) - For those who are wondering.

Comment: Have you cosidered [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) ? It does most of the things needed, but archive creation is not in its feature list.

Comment: @vonPryz I will ask professor if I can use robocopy, but I believe he want's pure powershell script here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use robocopy, in pure PowerShell code you could do this

```
$source  = 'path\gamybinis'  # no need for '\*' because you're specifying -Recurse
$dest    = 'path\backup'
$logFile = 'path\log.txt'

# test if the destination path exists. If not, create it first
if (!(Test-Path -Path $dest -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $dest -ItemType Directory
}

Write-Host "Backup started"
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -Force
        Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) - Copied file '$($_.FullName)'"
    }

Write-Host "Backup done"
```

---

From your comments, I understand you have problems when using the `-Container` switch.
Below code does not use that and creates the folder structure of the copied files in the backup folder, strictly using Powershell code:

```
$source  = 'path\gamybinis'  # no need for '\*' because you're specifying -Recurse
$dest    = 'path\backup'
$logFile = 'path\log.txt'

Write-Host "Backup started"
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -File -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $target = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($source.Length)
        if (!(Test-Path $target -PathType Container)) {
            # create the folder if it does not already exist
            $null = New-Item -Path $target -ItemType Directory
        }
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $target -Force
        Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) - Copied file '$($_.FullName)'"
    }

Write-Host "Backup done"
```

Comment: I asked and I can use robocopy, but because I was already pretty much done with this, I will just try both

Comment: Extra question: How can I preserve folder structure? I tried -Container but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Wowy Should work if you replace `$_ | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -Force` into `Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $dest -Recurse -Container -Force`. Apparently, if you pipe to Copy-Item, it will not preserve the folder structure. P.S. By default, the Container parameter is set to $true, so you could leave it out.

Comment: It still creates multiple copies of folders ex: path\gamybinis\subfolder\folder\folder2, this will lead to copying everything in this structure like this: path\backup\subfolder\folder\folder2, but I also get path\backup\subfolder, path\backup\folder, path\backup\folder2 and all the the files in between those folders

Comment: @Wowy I have added code for preserving the directory structure without using the `-Container` switch